# where to put a jQuery function inside an HTML document?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i found a worked example at this site http://jsfiddle.net/VNXb2/26/ , but when i put it at Aptana studio it doesn't work, i guess that i didn't put the function in the proper place, so where to put these function relative to the HTML in the first section,thanks.

Comment: You can put it at the bottom inside a script tag

Comment: If you are getting an 'Illegal token' error then it might be because you copy pased the code from jsFiddle. It has some characters that webkit breaks on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have javascript in a jQuery Mobile page that is loaded through ajax, you will need to put the `<script>` tags inside that pages `<div>`.  That means inside of the div that is marked `data-role="page"`.

Example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-1">
 ...
</div>
```

some other page loaded asynchronously

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-2">
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    <div data-role="content">...</div>
</div>
```

If you are just switching between jQM pages that are actually in the same document, you should be ok to put your function anywhere on that document, but probably preferably in the `<head>` tags.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret your comment, but I have updated my answer to show where the script tag would go if it was being retrieved in a page loaded by ajax in the jqm framework.

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle has a combo box on the left that says (in the link you posted) `onLoad`. This means this will be loaded when all the necessary things are loaded and DOM initialized as needed. Wrap the JS code within:

```
$(function() {
   // All JS code from there
});
```

and it should work. See this update:

- http://jsfiddle.net/VNXb2/27/

Comment: i tried to put that function in all the page parts and it still doesn't work!!

Comment: Just put the javascript part (bottom left on the jsfiddle) - see the example I gave, just copy paste the parts one after another and it should work.